# TextView and Button distance is constant, but wrap TextView when Button reaches end of parent

Tags: android

I'm new to Android so sorry for the basic question but I'm trying to create a view with a textview and button next to each other. The distance between them is constant; I want the button to hug the textview. If the textview has enough text that the button reaches the parent on the right, then I want the textview to wrap. In iOS you can set the textview to button constraint, then make a constraint between the button and margin with a value of "greater than or equal to x." I'm having a little trouble doing this in Android. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Which layout you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

[image]
[image]

This can be achieved with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```